# Django Form Validation Error Not Showing In Template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

my issue is exactly as the problem states...I am unable to get form validation errors to work.  I will post what I am currently trying below.  Please let me know how I can amend my code in order to get this working. Currently, I can even successfully submit the form with any name.  So clearly what I have set in forms.py is not even working...

forms.py

```
class PackingListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PackingList
        fields = ['Exporter', 'Consignee', 'Reference_Number', ... ]

    def clean_test_value(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data.get('Exporter')

        if not Exporter == 'Jeff':
            raise forms.ValidationError('ahhhh Error!')
        return data
```

template (packlist.html)

```
<td rowspan="3"colspan="2">Exporter: {{ form.Exporter }}
          {% for error in form.Exporter.errors %}
            <P class='help is-danger'>{{ error }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
</td>
```

views.py

```
def PackingListView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PackingListForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            .....do stuff here......

        else:

            return render(request, 'packlist.html', {'form': form})

    else:
        form = PackingListForm()
        return render(request, 'packlist.html', {'form': form})
```

traceback

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/create/packing_list

Django Version: 1.11
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'Poseidon',
 'crispy_forms',
 'bootstrap_modal_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/andrews/Desktop/WBU2/Poseidon/views.py" in PackingListView
  188.         if form.is_valid():

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  183.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  175.             self.full_clean()

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  384.         self._clean_fields()

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_fields
  405.                     value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()

File "/Users/andrews/Desktop/WBU2/Poseidon/forms.py" in clean_Exporter
  52.         if not Exporter == 'Greg':

Exception Type: NameError at /create/packing_list
Exception Value: global name 'Exporter' is not defined
```

Comment: The validator should be `clean_Exporter`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yeah thanks for the input. Very helpful. Question has already been answered.

Comment: @GXM100 learning to read tracebacks and error messages would help you indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the name of the field is `Exporter`, the cleaning function should be `clean_Exporter`:

```
class PackingListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PackingList
        fields = ['Exporter', 'Consignee', 'Reference_Number']

    def clean_Exporter(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data.get('Exporter')

        if data != 'Jeff':
            raise forms.ValidationError('ahhhh Error!')
        return data
```

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, so it should be: `exporter` instead of <s>`Exporter`</s>.

Comment: Hi Willem - this was helpful, but now I see to be missing something in my view because I immediately get a NameError upon submission of the form which states 'global name Exporter is not defined'.  I have posted the traceback above.

Comment: @GXM100: yes, it should be `not data == `, not `not Exporter ==`, since you did not define that variable :)

Comment: @GXM100: you can also use `data != 'Jeff'` which is shorter.

Comment: Thank you! everything seems to be working now...relatively easy things but overlooked because I'm new to this...appreciate your help.